# Problems using aspnet_compiler to compile a fresh ASP.NET MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, cruisecontrol.net

I recently updated a project in my solution to use MVC 3 instead of MVC 2.

Ever since doing that, and although it compiles in my machine, I get the following error in the server:

```
/MyProject.csproj/global.asax (1,0):

    errorASPPARSE: Could not load type 'MyNamespace.MvcApplication'.
```

Any ideas?

- It compiles and works ok in my machine.
- It compiles in the server if I open it in a VS.NET 2010.
- It compiles in the server via msbuild.

**UPDATE**:
The exact command that fails is this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /MyProject.csproj -p c:\cruisecontrol\trunk.project\checkout\Solution\Project -u -f .\TempBuildDir\
```

If I open the VS.NET 2010 in the server, compile it once manually, the command then runs ok.

The problem is that my CC.NET deletes everything and then checks it out from source control from scratch, so this approach doesn't work for me. Although it's interesting because it's weird.

**UPDATE 2:**
I was able to reproduce this locally, so it's not a problem specifically in the CC.NET server.
Could someone try to reproduce it?

MVC 3 application with razor (although I doubt it'd make a difference), run aspnet_compiler on it, and see if it fails with that error. Just close VS.NET as soon as it creates the solution and the project.

[image]

This does not happen if I compile it at least once with Visual Studio

If someone is kind enough to try it, I can rule out a problem in the 2 machines I tested.

Comment: Try putting the MVC Dlls System.Web.Mvc etc. in the bin folder of your Web application.... Maybe it can't load them from GAC

Comment: @Varun, I'll try that, but wouldn't the msbuild compilation also fail if that was the problem?

Comment: I encountered a similar problem sometime back and adding the DLLs helped, so I thought maybe you are facing such a problem.... Do post the answer here once you figure it out :-)

Comment: Re-installing the assembly in the GAC did not fix the problem =(

Comment: I'm curious what compiling with VS.NET generates that allows it compile AFTER that.  Perhaps it moves the MyNamespace.MvcApplication dll somewhere that your CC is expecting it?

Comment: @Nick, I'm curious too... I still haven't figured it out what is happening (VS.NET does not give me a detailed build output... I'd like to compare what parameters it passes to aspnet_compiler.exe, it might be different) -- for now I've solved it by having CC.NET do an update instead of delete/checkout, but this is only a temporary solution.

Comment: Did you try placing the DLLs in the bin folder (not reinstalling them in GAC but placing them in the bin folder of your web app)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently aspnet_compiler.exe required that the /bin directory exists, that's why building it once with vs.net fixes the consecutive compilations using aspnet_compiler.exe.

I don't know why this worked before changing my application from mvc 2 to mvc 3, but I fixed it by changing a property in the .wdproj file

From

`<SourceWebPhysicalPath>..\..\Project\</SourceWebPhysicalPath>`

To

`<SourceWebPhysicalPath>..\..\Project\bin</SourceWebPhysicalPath>`

[Source](http://gbarrs.blogspot.com/2009/03/error-aspparse-could-not-load-type.html)